# Customizing Resolution and FPS in Anbox Cloud Appliance Session

Tags: display, display-resolution, anbox

Anbox Cloud is the mobile cloud computing platform delivered by Canonical. I have set up an Anbox cloud appliance on a dedicated server and am looking to initiate a session with a customized resolution and frame rate, specifically 1024x768 at 15fps. However, when I start the session through the Anbox UI and input the extra data {"display_width":1024,"display_height":768,"fps":15}, it defaults to the standard screen format.

Is there a way to successfully set a custom resolution and fps for a session in Anbox Cloud Appliance?